# Hibernate Mapping Classes

Tags: java, hibernate

The scenario is following: Im implementing a shoppingcart, where a Customer can choose products from a productcatalog.

I have issues with the mapping of my Java classes in Hibernate correctly, maybe you can help me.

```
public class Shoppingcart { 
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cartID")
    private Set<ShoppingcartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>();
    //...
}
```

```
public class Customer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="CUSTID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERLASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    //...
}
```

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private double price;
    private String product;
    //...
}
```

```
public class ShoppingcartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long itemId; 
    private Shoppingcart shoppingcart; 
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
    private int amount; 
    //...
}
```

---

My DB structure is the following:

Customer

- id
- fistname
- lastname

Shoppingcart

- id
- customer

Shoppingcart_item

- id
- cartId
- productId
- amount

Product

- id
- price
- name

---

When i run my code I get the following exception:
 `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.OrderManagementMaven.bo.ShoppingcartItem.product references an unknown entity: com.OrderManagementMaven.bo.Product`

What are my Mistakes / what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

Your entities are missing the `@Entity` annotation:

```java
@Entity
public class Shoppingcart { 
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="cartID")
    private Set<ShoppingcartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>();
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Customer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="CUSTID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERFIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="CUSTOMERLASTNAME")
    private String lastname;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private double price;
    private String product;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class ShoppingcartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long itemId; 
    private Shoppingcart shoppingcart; 
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
    private int amount;    
    //...
}
```